# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

i add a dependency lib ,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
}
```

then i wish it can be download automatically, then refresh the external libriaries,so that the lib commons-lang3 will be shown in the external libriaries.

the detail message about the bug is :

https://github.com/SnowdreamFramework/android-log/issues/3

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-139.225.3, 11 Nov 2014 00:00)
GRADLE: 2.2.1
Android Plugin:         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86)
JRE: 1.8.0_25-b18 (Oracle Corporation)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Buried deep in that log file is a line that suggests that you have a badly configured Nexus repository (github is not a nexus repo):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: File: http://snowdream.github.io/mvn-repo/snapshots/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties , ReasonPhrase:Not Found.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:883)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.retrieve(Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.java:100)
```

Comment: I think it is just a warning，but not the reason for the problem above.